# doWithSpring in Grails 3 plugin as a subproject

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-plugin

I have a project built with Gradle with 3 subprojects: trawler, adaptrice, frontage. Trawler is Groovy/Java, adaptrice is a Grails 3.1.7 app, frontage is a Grails 3 plugin used by adaptrice.

The top *settings.gradle* says `include 'trawler', 'adaptrice', 'frontage'`, *adaptrice/build.gradle* contains,

```
grails {
  plugins {
    compile project(':frontage')
  }
}
```

All this as per the Grails documentation. Everything works -- almost. The `doWithSpring` method in the plugin descriptor (class `FrontageGrailsPlugin`) looks like this,

```
Closure doWithSpring() { {->
  entityPropGrabberFactory(EntityPropGrabberFactory) {
    constraintsEvaluator = ref(ConstraintsEvaluator.BEAN_NAME)
    proxyHandler = ref('proxyHandler')
  }
}}
```

It is never executed when I do run-app for the adaptrice Grails app. There is a NPE when a supposedly injected bean is used. If I move the body of `doWithSpring` to the *.../spring/resources.groovy* of the adaptrice Grails app then it really works.

So my question is, what causes the `doWithSpring` in a Grails 3 plugin descriptor to be executed? Do I have to do something special when the plugin also is a subproject?

Comment: Does you plugin `FrontageGrailsPlugin` extend `Plugin` ?

Comment: Yes, sure. The plugin descriptor class was generated by "create-plugin".